# Copy stock data from one cell every minute and make table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file of my stocks portfolio. There is a macro running all the time which refreshes the whole workbook every 30 seconds to update the change. I want to write a code which will put values in a new cell when the workbook refreshes.
For example, a stock price is $10 right now and enter $10 in A1, after 30 seconds, it changes to $11 and A2 will have $11 but A1 remain $10.

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Sub ValueStore()
Dim dTime As Date
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
    Call StartTimer
End Sub



Sub StartTimer()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

I have above code. It stops updating at row# 64. I have no idea why.

Comment: I would guess that your problem comes from unqualified Ranges. `Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp)` will count the number of rows of the ActiveSheet, not of Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

*The code is not stopping at row# 64.*

If you observe `Sheet2`, you'll notice that the code after writing at cell `[A64]` writes all the next entries at cell `[A4]`.

The problem lies within this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value _
    = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
```

specifically in this part:

```
Cells(Rows.Count).Row)
```

and it's not because of the unqualified Range, instead is due to the following:

This part `Rows.Count`, although unqualified, returns the number of rows of the `ActiveSheet` *(i.e. 65536 Excel 2003 version or 1048576 Excel 2010 and later)*. However, if the `ActiveSheet` is a `Chart` it will generate a `Runtime Error: 1004 - Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' failed`. To ensure the correct return, it's always better to qualify it this way: `Object.Rows.Count` where the object could be a worksheet or a range.

The problem comes when `Rows.Count` is used as a `Cell.Index` like in this case: `Cells(Rows.Count)`. This way it returns the 1048576th cell *(Excel 2010 and later)* of the sheet starting from cell `[A1]` which is the cell `[XFD64]` thus making `Row(64)` the last row.

That’s the reason for which the code writes continuously from cell `[A4]` to `[A64]`, after which the code only writes in cell `[A4]` given the impression that it stopped at cell `[A64]`.

Try this code:

```
Public md_Time As Date

Sub ValueStore()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Columns(1).Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = _
            .Parent.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
    End With
    Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
    md_Time = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)
    Application.OnTime md_Time, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. It really helped a lot. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
'Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 10
Public Const cRunWhat = "FindStockFinal"
Public LastRow As Long
Public StartColumn As Long
Public Lastcol As Long


Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub


Public Sub FindStockFinal()

Const HeaderRow = 3

Dim IE As Object
Dim URLLOOKUP As String
Dim NewCol As Integer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

URLLOOKUP = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cq?d=v1&s="

With Sheets("Enter Open Long")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & HeaderRow).End(xlDown).Row
    Lastcol = .Cells(HeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    StartColumn = Lastcol + 1
    Set StockNames = .Range("A" & (HeaderRow + 1) & ":A" & LastRow)
    StockName = ""
    For Each cell In StockNames
       If StockName = "" Then
          StockName = cell
       Else
           StockName = StockName & "%20" & cell
       End If
    Next cell
      
      URL = URLLOOKUP & StockName

      'get web page
      IE.Navigate2 URL
      Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or _
         IE.Busy = True
         DoEvents
      Loop
      
      'leave one row for header row
      RowCount = HeaderRow
      Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
      Set Table = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
      For Each TableRow In Table(0).Rows
         If RowCount = HeaderRow Then
            .Cells(RowCount, StartColumn) = "Start"
         Else
            .Cells(RowCount, StartColumn).Value = TableRow.Cells(2).innertext
         End If
         RowCount = RowCount + 1
      Next TableRow
      
      Dim i As Long
      Dim rng As Range
      Dim iCol As Long
      Dim num As Long
      .Cells(HeaderRow, StartColumn + 1) = "Change"
      Set FormulaRange = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, StartColumn + 1), _
         .Cells(LastRow, StartColumn + 1))
      FormulaRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=(RC[-1]/RC2)-1"
            
      Set RowOffset50 = FormulaRange.Offset(rowoffset:=50, columnoffset:=0)
      RowOffset50.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=if(R[-50]C>=.02,0,-1)"
      RowOffset50.Copy
      RowOffset50.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      
      For Each cell In RowOffset50
         If cell.Value = -1 Then
            StockName = .Cells(cell.Row, "A")
            On Error Resume Next
            Set c = StockNames.Find(what:=StockName, _
               LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
               c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
         End If
      Next cell
      .Cells(1, StartColumn).Select
End With

IE.Quit
StartTimer
End Sub
```

[image]

Try that and feed back.

Answer (score -1):

Something is wrong in your code.
I think you hit a 'stack overflow' : 64 probably is the maximum of subsequent function calls in vba.

The ValueStore sub should'nt call StartTimer.

You just should call the StartTimer sub in the Workbook_open event.
This sub has to reschedule itself and call ValueStore.

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "StartTimer", Schedule:=True
    Call ValueStore
End Sub

Sub ValueStore()
Dim dTime As Date
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
   'remove this line : Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code. Have same problem. Stops at row#64